# How can I generate token list of given length and use it in tabular environment?

Tags: latex

I am trying to build a LaTeX environment such that for every integer N,

```
\begin{mytab}{N}
% foo bar
\end{mytab}
```

would expand to

```
\begin{tabular}{lr.....lr}
% foo bar
\end{tabular}
```

with N token pairs "lr".

Here is my poor attempt at doing it.  I feel I am on the right track, as 
`\mytokens` is the token list I want.  If only it would work when I replace the `\junk` by `\mytokens` on the next to last line...

```
\newcounter{ct}
\newenvironment{mytab}[1]{%
  \setcounter{ct}{#1}
  \newcommand{\mytokens}{%
     \ifthenelse{\thect>0}{\addtocounter{ct}{-1}lr\mytokens}{}
  }
  \def\junk{lrlrlrlrlrlr}
  \expandafter\tabular\expandafter{\junk}%
}{
  \endtabular
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can repeat column definitions with `*`:

```
\begin{tabular}{*{6}{lr}}
 %...
\end{tabular}
```

Comment: Yeah! That does the trick! Thanks a lot. Still, I wonder why my poor attempt does not work...

Comment: @Guillaume: It would certainly help if you posted the error instead of "it does not work".

Comment: sorry I did not include the error. I tried so many things that did not work, it did not seem very pertinent to include it. Since your solution solves the problem, I think I am giving up on my attempt. Thanks again!